# Cannot load pulseaudio modules via pactl: `Failure: no such entity`

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth

I can no longer get pulseaudio to recognize my bluetooth headphones (worked until yesterday).

`pulseaudio` state:

```
$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/505443/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 34
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 65
Tile Size: 65472
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.38)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Cookie: 97f6:1e4d
```

```
$ pactl list sinks short 
49  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

```
$ pactl list modules short
pactl list modules short 
1   libpipewire-module-rtkit    {
            #nice.level   = -11
            #rt.prio      = 88
            #rt.time.soft = 2000000
            #rt.time.hard = 2000000
        }   
2   libpipewire-module-protocol-native      
3   libpipewire-module-profiler     
5   libpipewire-module-metadata     
7   libpipewire-module-spa-device-factory       
9   libpipewire-module-spa-node-factory     
11  libpipewire-module-client-node      
13  libpipewire-module-client-device        
15  libpipewire-module-portal       
16  libpipewire-module-access   {
            # access.allowed to list an array of paths of allowed
            # apps.
            #access.allowed = [
            #    /usr/bin/pipewire-media-session
            #]

            # An array of rejected paths.
            #access.rejected = [ ]

            # An array of paths with restricted access.
            #access.restricted = [ ]

            # Anything not in the above lists gets assigned the
            # access.force permission.
            #access.force = flatpak
        }   
17  libpipewire-module-adapter      
19  libpipewire-module-link-factory     
21  libpipewire-module-session-manager
```

Note how there is no bluetooth module listed. I can't load them either:

```
$ pactl load-module module-bluez5-discover 
Failure: No such entity
$ pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover 
Failure: No such entity
```

The corresponding Debian package is installed:

```
$ dpkg -l pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                        Version      Architecture Description
+++-===========================-============-============-============================================
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth 14.2-2       amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
```

What could be the issue?

Note I've also tried restarting pulseaudio multiple times:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio -D
$ pulseaudio --start
```

Comment: Did you recently update pulseaudio or pulseaudio-module-bluetooth?

Comment: Not knowingly, but it's entirely possible apt-get did this in the background

Comment: I just gave up on pulseaudio in the end and switched to [PipeWire](https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the package `pipewire-audio-client-libraries` which will add `module-tunnel-sink` `module-zeroconf-discover` and `bluetooth`. Those are now handled by `pipewire` since 0.3.28. `apt install` that and it will work like before.

Since Debian 11 you need to get to know about `pipewire`. Most config is now in `/usr/share/pipewire`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note, that I also had to install pipewire-audio. Not sure if my system is running on pulseaudio or pipewire now...